# My views are not rendering the text that was inputted into the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm squeezing my way through learning Rails, but for some reason my views are not being rendered correctly!

When I input information into the form on the 'docs/new' page via the web browser, the text is not rendered that's stored in the variables. Rather, it's literally the instance variables that are rendered.

I am using the simple_form gem as well as the haml gem.

EDIT: I'm using Rails 4.2.5 as well as the C9 IDE if that makes any difference

[This is the formatting I want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW1ih.png)

[This is the formatting I'm getting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oirpi.png)

Controller:

```
class DocsController < ApplicationController

before_action :find_doc, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
end

def show
end

def new
    @doc = Doc.new
end

def create
    @doc = Doc.new(doc_params)

    if @doc.save
        redirect_to @doc 
    else
        render 'new' 
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
end

def destroy
end

private

def find_doc
    @doc = Doc.find(params[:id])
end

def doc_params
    params.require(:doc).permit(:title, :content)
end
```

end

_form.html.haml:

```
= simple_form_for @doc do |f|
= f.input :title
= f.input :content
= f.button :submit
```

show.html.haml :

```
%h1= @doc.title
%p= @doc.content
```

new.html.haml :

```
%h1 New Doc!

= render 'form'
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think indentation in your form is not correct. Try this:

```
= simple_form_for @doc do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :content
  = f.button :submit 

And in show.html.haml:

%h1
  = @doc.title
%p
  = @doc.content
```

Answer (score 0):

In your show.haml I think you are not rendering the variable.  With haml you have to be very specific with rendering.  Put the instance on a new line with proper spacing

```
%h1
  = @doc.title
%p
  = @doc.content
```

If you are just getting starting you may consider switching to erb for rendering until you get the gist of how rails/ruby work and then switch over to haml later

Comment: Thank you! I got it down now!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define @doc in your Show action in the controller. That is why:

```
@doc.title
@doc.content
```

Is displayed literally.

In your show actions update it like this:

```
def show
  @doc = Doc.find(params[:id])
end
```